# Send javaScript score from a game to PHP using hidden form - i dont get any value?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hello i want to send the score from a game(JS) to php so i can later store it in my database. But i dont get any value when i click a submit button to save all the score. I am using a hidden form.

As you can see i have a tabel with xWon, xLose, and so on... When i play a game evertthing works and the score from the JS is posted in that tabel. But when i hit the submit button i dont get any values when i use echo in the top of my code..?
Here is the HTML code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['xWon_score']) && isset($_POST['xLose_score']) && 
isset($_POST['drawGame_score']) && isset($_POST['totalGames_score']))
{

$xWon_score = $_POST['xWon_score'];
$xLose_score = $_POST['xLose_score'];
$drawGame_score = $_POST['drawGame_score'];
$totalGames_score = $_POST['totalGames_score'];


echo $xWon_score . $xLose_score . $drawGame_score . $totalGames_score;
}else
echo "Testing......";

?>


<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="scripts/game.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles/general.css">
</head>

<body onload="startGame();">

    <table border="1" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>X won</td>
        <td>X lose</td>
        <td>Draw</td>
        <td>Total games</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="xWon_score">0</td>
        <td id="xLose_score">0</td>
        <td id="drawGame_score">0</td>
        <td id="totalGames_score">0</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>


    <div id="button_div">
    <br>
    <button id="button" type="button" onclick="alert('Restarting game')"><a href="javascript:startGame();">New Game</a></button>

<!-- Problem section ????? -->  

    <form method="post" action="game.php">  
        <input type="hidden" value="" id="Won_score" name="xWon_score"/>
        <input type="hidden" value="" id="Lose_score" name="xLose_score"/>
        <input type="hidden" value="" id="draw_score" name="drawGame_score"/>
        <input type="hidden" value="" id="total_score" name="totalGames_score"/>

        <!-- Save highscore button -->
        <button type="submit" onclick="alert('Saving highscore')">Save highscore</button>

        </form>
```

And here is the function to print the JS score:

```
    function recordWin(winner){
                    if (winner == "X"){
                        xWon++;
                        totalGames++;
                    }else if (winner == "O"){
                        xLose++;
                        totalGames++;
                    }else if (winner ==""){
                        drawGame++;
                        totalGames++;
                    }saveStats();
                }

                function saveStats(recordWin){

                    document.getElementById("xWon_score").innerText = xWon;
                    document.getElementById("xLose_score").innerText = xLose;
                    document.getElementById("drawGame_score").innerText = drawGame;
                    document.getElementById("totalGames_score").innerText = totalGames;

    // Somthing Wrong here?
document.getElementById("Won_score").value = xWon;
document.getElementById("Lose_score").value = xLose;
document.getElementById("draw_score").value = drawGame;
document.getElementById("total_score").value = totalGames;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried just sending the ajax call directly, instead of using a form?

Comment: Hello, hmm not sure on how to do that. I am new to all this stuff, i have only used some html javascript and php.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is this:

```
document.getElementById("myInput").value;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_hidden_value.asp

```
 document.getElementById("Won_score").value = xWon;
 document.getElementById("Lose_score").value = xLose;
 document.getElementById("draw_score").value = drawGame;
 document.getElementById("total_score").value = totalGames;
```

Comment: Hello thx for the answer! I changed to that syntax, but i still dont get any values when i click submit button. (checking with echo)

Comment: what happens if you print the complete GET array. Do you get anything at all? `print_r($_GET);`

Comment: Hmm not sure where to put that in my code? print_r($_GET);

Comment: Add "print_r($_REQUEST);" before the line "if(isset($_POST['xWon_score']) && isset($_POST['xLose_..."

Comment: Ok, i have done that now. When i refresh the page, this is displayed.
Array ( [Won_score] => [xLose_score] => [drawGame_score] => [totalGames_score] => ) Testing.....

Comment: Where's the event that calls `recordWin()`? I assume somewhere in `startGame` but from what I see `recordWin()` isn't being called.

Comment: Yes that event is further up in my JS game, code. The game itself works good, and while i play the game tic-tac-toe, i can see my results in my tabel.
 
         <td id="xWon_score">0</td>
        <td id="xLose_score">0</td>
        <td id="drawGame_score">0</td>
        <td id="totalGames_score">0</td>

Answer (score 0):

Well assuming everything is being called correctly it should be working with your latest changes.

The only suggestion I can make would be to use `document.formName.formElementName.value` as opposed `document.getElementById('formElementId').value`

Here's an example using `ajax` with `POST` values and its response.

http://jsfiddle.net/pL1wouj7/

**HTML**

```
<form name="scores" method="post" onsubmit="return ajax(this)">
    <select id="winner">
        <option>X</option>
        <option>O</option>
        <option value=""></option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" value="" id="Won_score" name="xWon_score"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="" id="Lose_score" name="xLose_score"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="" id="draw_score" name="drawGame_score"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="" id="total_score" name="totalGames_score"/>

    <button type="button" onclick="recordWin()">Record Winner</button>
    <button type="submit">Save Scores</button>     
</form>
<div id="response">

</div>
```

---

**Javascript**

```
var xWon = 0;
var xLose = 0;
var drawGame = 0;
var totalGames = 0;

function recordWin() {
  var winner = document.getElementById("winner").value;
  if (winner == "X"){
      xWon++;
      totalGames++;
  }else if (winner == "O"){
      xLose++;
      totalGames++;
  }else if (winner ==""){
      drawGame++;
      totalGames++;
  }
  saveStats();
}

function saveStats() {
    document.scores.xWon_score.value = xWon;
    document.scores.xLose_score.value = xLose;
    document.scores.drawGame_score.value = drawGame;
    document.scores.totalGames_score.value = totalGames;
}

function ajax(oForm) {
    var data = 'html=<ul><li>won: '+oForm.xWon_score.value+'</li><li>lose: '+oForm.xLose_score.value+'</li><li>draw: '+oForm.drawGame_score.value+'</li><li>total: '+ oForm.totalGames_score.value + '</li></ul>';

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('post', '/echo/html/', true);
    xhr.onload = function() { 
        document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = this.responseText; 
    };
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send(data);
    return false;
}
```

Also make sure there are no errors occurring by checking your Developer Tools Console (F12 in Chrome/FireFox).

[image: Dev Tools]

Comment: Hello thx for the sugestions, i will try! 
Any way i can msg you if i have a question? I cant find any msg function on your profile? (new to this forum)

Comment: You can just add a comment here to message me. Only other thing I can think of is that an error may be causing your form not to update. try checking with your developer tools. [Dev Tools](http://i.imgur.com/wom31pz.png?1)